# SQL NOT IN() not working, returning data it shouldn't

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, ssms, sql-insert

The below sproc should NOT try to insert any records if they exist in both my temp table "r" or the actual table I'm trying to insert them into "record".

I'm getting primary key constraint errors because it the NOT IN function still trys to insert records that ARE ALREADY IN the record table.

Can someone take a look at my code below and tell me if this is the correct way to do this?

```
    INSERT INTO [RxEvidence].[Record] ([RecordID], [Source], [Notes], [ReceivedFrom], [ReceivedDate], [CompleteDate])
    SELECT r.[RecordID], r.[Source], r.[Notes], r.[ReceivedFrom], r.[ReceivedDate], r.[CompleteDate]
    FROM @Records r WHERE r.RecordID NOT IN (SELECT RecordId FROM RxEvidence.Record)
    GROUP BY r.[RecordID], r.[Source], r.[Notes], r.[ReceivedFrom], r.[ReceivedDate], r.[CompleteDate];
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: This is something `EXCEPT` might be able to do you for you without the need for grouping (assuming the rows can or should be matched on all columns rather than just ID).

Comment: Sorry, as this is production data I'm not sure what sample to include.

@Records contains a RecordID that already exists in the RxEvidence.Record table, therefore it shouldn't try to add it to the table given the "NOT IN", but it still does, which results in primary key constraint errors.  

I guess I was just hoping someone could spot if this was written wrong given that info.

Comment: `MERGE` might be useful here, as it allows you to only insert records where there is no matching record in your target table.

Comment: @DeanOC I thought about trying something other than NOT IN like MERGE, but I'd like to understand why the way it is written isn't working.

Comment: Why you have GROUP BY at the end?

Comment: The sentence is not complex at all so I have to believe the primary key exceptions are correct. So I guess the primary key is a composite key as the RecordID comes from an external source. Just guessing, but it would make sense if the primary key was {RecordId, Source}

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
INSERT INTO RxEvidence.Record (RecordID, [Source], Notes, ReceivedFrom, ReceivedDate, CompleteDate)
SELECT r.RecordID, r.[Source], r.Notes, r.ReceivedFrom, r.ReceivedDate, r.CompleteDate
FROM @Records r 
WHERE not exists (select 1 
                  from RxEvidence.Record rr
                  where r.RecordID=rr.RecordId);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems both @Records and RxEvidence.Record have a RecordId column, so to remove any possibility that the wrong one is getting picked up, could try using a table alias (
"x" in example below) in the SELECT statement here:

```
FROM @Records r WHERE r.RecordID NOT IN (SELECT x.RecordId FROM RxEvidence.Record x)
```

It may not be the problem, but shouldn't hurt, at least.
What are the data types of the RecordId column in RxEvidence.Record and @Records? Are they the same? Is there an insert trigger on the RxEvidence.Record table?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using NOT EXISTS or a join instead of NOT IN.  NOT IN does not work as expected when you're dealing with NULL values.

Consider this script

```
set nocount on
drop table if exists #src;
drop table if exists #dest;

select * into #src from (values (1),(2),(3),(4))x (col_src) 
select * from #src 
    
select * into #dest from (values (2),(4),(5))z(col_dest) where col_dest not in (select col_src from #src)
select * from #dest
```

The result is the following (which is correct):

```
col_src
-----------
1
2
3
4

col_dest
-----------
5
```

Now, change the script to replace 3 by null

```
set nocount on
drop table if exists #src;
drop table if exists #dest;

select * into #src from (values (1),(2),(null),(4))x (col_src) 
select * from #src 


select * into #dest from (values (2),(4),(5))z(col_dest) where col_dest not in (select col_src from #src)
select * from #dest
```

The result is not what you would expected.

```
col_src
-----------
1
2
NULL
4

col_dest
-----------
```

And you'll get the same unwanted result when the where clause is something like " where null not in (select ..... )".

For a better explanation (and more detail), read this chapter "Handling changes in nullability: NOT IN versus NOT EXISTS"
http://assets.red-gate.com/community/books/defensive-database-programming.pdf